# MySQL where NOT IN name array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to exclude these albums, that has name:

```
$ban_album_names = array('Wall', 'Profile', 'Cover', 'Instagram');
```

How do I write correctly,

```
SELECT * FROM albums WHERE name NOT IN ???
```

How can I make it look in the array, and if the name matches it should != the row

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM albums
    WHERE name NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $ban_album_names ) . "' )";
```

Comment: For the given list of names, there aren't any embedded quotes in the strings; if there were, you'd need to create the `$banned` list calling an appropriate quoting function to prevent [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327).

Comment: This is a terrible answer and will result in a bunch of unnecessary queries. Look below.

Comment: How about when you have an array of ID's, integers?

Comment: this parameter order may have been appropriate at the time of writing. however, for people who come across it now note that the documented order is the 'glue' first, and then the array. technically they both work still, but this is not the documented order.

Answer (score 38):

The MySQL CODE is

```
SELECT * FROM albums WHERE name NOT IN ('Wall', 'Profile', 'Cover', 'Instagram')
```