# Rails scope select where all values are in a list

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I've got a rails scope that looks something like this:

```
default_scope joins(:groups).where("groups.name in ('GROUP1','GROUP2')")
```

Which filters my model objects where they aren't in GROUP1 or GROUP2, but I need to find a way to filter model objects where they don't have GROUP1 *and* GROUP2.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add another condition and replace 'in' with 'not in'.

Comment: I don't see how that helps...

Comment: Please try this `default_scope joins(:groups).where("groups.name NOT IN ('GROUP1','GROUP2')")`

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230338/mysql-where-not-in-name-array

Comment: I also need results where the model has a subset of the list, so if just GROUP1.

Comment: `default_scope joins(:groups).where("groups.name like %GROUP1%")`

Comment: @rich if it is acceptable then I can post it ...

Comment: Didn't seem to work either, because the previous filter doesn't include it.

Comment: I thought this had done it: joins(:groups).where("groups.id not in (select id from groups where name not in ('GROUP1','GROUP2'))") but it appears to still include items with GROUP1 if I remove it from the list.